# play music from a stream using Jukebox - Swift, IOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want to stream music to my app using this library I found online called Jukebox. Heres a link to their page: https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox

I keep getting an error saying "use of unresolved identifier 'Jukebox'" and "use of unresolved identifier 'JukeboxItem' "

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self, items: 
    [JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/2514.mp3")!)
 ]) }

@IBAction func Play(sender: UIButton) {
    self.jukebox.play()
}
```

I also get an error by the play button saying "value of type 'ViewController' has no member of 'jukebox'"
where am i going wrong? I have the pods correctly installed and everything. Thanks

Comment: were is "jukebox" created, please post that code, but most important its **position**.

Comment: hey Eric, thanks for responding, jukebox is a pod I installed

Comment: yes, but where do you create the jukebox object? or is it pre-created for you?

Comment: no, sorry I'm really new to this, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't really know much about pods, I just noticed that jukebox is never created so therefore it isn't recognized by the compiler

Comment: I fixed the top issues by importing jukebox and initializing it, but now I receive an error on the third line right where it says 'Jukebox(delegate: self ' the error says "cannot convert the argument of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'JukeboxDelegate?'

Comment: try `delegate: self.delegate`

Answer (score 1):

Above viewDidLoad() you need to instantiate jukebox like this:

```
var jukebox : Jukebox!
```